# Resorting A std::multiset Container

Tags: c++

In my program when I make a change, I want to reorder my set but when I call these two alternative functions I get an iterator not incrementable error. I realised that the problem occurs when I call clear() or swap(). How can I correct this code or is there any other way to do the rearranging?

```
void CObjectHandling::ReOrder()
{
    multiset<IDrawable*, Drawable_compare> TmpContainer;

    for (auto i = mDrawableReferences.begin(); i != mDrawableReferences.end(); ++i)
    {
        TmpContainer.insert(*i);
    }

    mDrawableReferences.clear();

    for (auto i = TmpContainer.begin(); i != TmpContainer.end(); ++i)
    {
        mDrawableReferences.insert(*i);
    }

    TmpContainer.clear();

}
```

.

```
void CObjectHandling::ReOrder()
{
    multiset<IDrawable*, Drawable_compare> TmpContainer;

    for (auto i = mDrawableReferences.begin(); i != mDrawableReferences.end(); ++i)
    {
        TmpContainer.insert(*i);
    }

    mDrawableReferences.swap(TmpContainer);
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error you get, and on which line?

Comment: You can also remove the loops by doing a [range insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/insert): `TmpContainer.insert(mDrawableReferences.begin(), mDrawableReferences.end())`

Comment: @Collin Dauphinee The program is compiling. ReOrder function is called with a mouse button release. When I release the button compiler throws an iterator not incrementable error. But when I comment swap() or clear() out program doesn't throw any erros when mouse released (Beacuse this causes multisets' size to be doubled on every mouse release it causes the program to crash. - I did this to detect the problem anyway).